# harmony between webflow and Spring MVC Controllers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Spring 2.5.6SEC02
Spring Webflow 2.0.9

I have a normal flow in which I have a form in flow scope.  I now want to call my annotated spring MVC @Controller and get access to the form information.  I basically want to display details as a modal dialog box on the screen.  I've been reading up on spring-js, but I'm not very familiar with it and it seems to want to incorporate dojo into my code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the form in session scope instead, that way it is available both to webflow and other controllers. That will however mean that it is shared between tabs and possibly reused in later conversations (Though you can probably prevent that).

Another solution is passing the flow execution key to the controller and have the controller read it from the FlowExecutionRepository.